# How to add 3 drop down in single variable in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, addition

Two days ago I had an interview as a php developer and they gave me a task to perform.
I completed 90% of the task, but I failed while trying to add date, month and year together.

I have 3 dropdowns for date, month and year:

```php
Date Of Birth : <br />
Date : <select name="date">
            <?php $i=1; for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){ ?> <option> <?php echo $i?> </option> <?php } ?>    
       </select>  
Month :  <select name="month">
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option>Febuary</option>
            <option>March</option>
            <option>April</option>
            <option>May</option>
            <option>June</option>
            <option>July</option>
            <option>August</option>
            <option>September</option>
            <option>October</option>
            <option>November</option>
            <option>December</option>

        </select>
Year :    
<?php
    $currently_selected = date('Y'); 
    $earliest_year = 1950; 
    $latest_year = date('Y'); 

    print '<select name="year">';
    foreach ( range( $latest_year, $earliest_year ) as $i ) {
    print '<option value="'.$i.'"'.($i === $currently_selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    print '</select>';
?>
```

I have only one column in the database for the date of birth.
I want to add the date, month and year together, which should result in the following: `date/month/year`.
How could I accomplish this?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = trim($_POST['username']);
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];

    if($name == ''){
        $error = "Add Name";
    }    

    $DateOfBirth = $date.'/'$month;

    if(!$error){
        echo $DateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Comment: update code like this. you don't need to convert date. you can update as you store in the DateOfBirth variable.                                                                                        
 $DateOfBirth = $date.'/'.$month.'/'.$date ;   // all value store in DateOfBirth valiable.                                                                      as said @Nipun Tharuksha. thanks

Comment: @JackTech I think it will be great if you mark an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your are not concatenating the variables in php. Check below code. You are almost there but with small coding mistake.

What you are trying to do is concatenate a variable with a string. So you have to concatenate variable with a '.' and then add your string. In here `/` works as the string. When adding a string it should be with in quotations `'/'` . And the final output will be something like this. `$variable . '/'`. Now concatenate another variable. Then it would be like this. `$variable01 . '/' . $variable02`.

```
 $DateOfBirth = $date.'/'.$month.'/'.$date ;
```

Output

```
12/02/2020
```

Check the added example with respect to your requirement

[example](https://3v4l.org/0NBQl)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your date of birth field is a MySQL `DATE` field, you need to make sure that you are creating a date in the correct format i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`. You can do that by using [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime) to convert your input data into a timestamp, and then [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert that into the appropriate format:

```
$DateOfBirth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$date $month $year"));
```

For example:

```
$year = 2015;
$month = 'August';
$date = 5;
$DateOfBirth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$date $month $year"));
echo $DateOfBirth;
```

Output:

```
2015-08-05
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6EdOc)

**Note**

If you *really* want the result to be in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, just change the first input to `date` to `'d/m/Y'`.